# SharePoint via Web Service- GetList items and build SQL table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

Scenraio:  I don't have access to run the program on the same server as SharePoint. I just can access
to SharePoint server Url. So I opted accessing the SharePoint service using a web reference to access a SharePoint 2010 list.

Here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace SPTechOpsProjectTracker
{
    class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Add a reference to my web service
        TechOpsProjectWebService.Lists listService = new TechOpsProjectWebService.Lists();
        //use the logged in user’s credentials
        listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        String listGUID = "a486016e-80b2-44c3-8b4a-8394574b9430";
        String activeItemViewGUID = "60689d51-5787-4ef1-9515-c050f20fa424 ";
        //calling the GetListItems service to return the 1000 list items 
        //for theparticular list and view that you pass to the function
        System.Xml.XmlNode activeItemData = listService.GetListItems(listGUID, activeItemViewGUID, null, null, "1000", null, "");

        // Go through the list to see what was returned

    foreach(System.Xml.XmlNode listItem in activeItemData) 
    {
     // Get the attributes
     System.Xml.XmlAttributeCollection attrs = listItem.Attributes;
     Console.WriteLine(listItem.OuterXml);
     Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue"); 
     Console.ReadLine();

    }

     //connect to my SQL server 2008 server

     //Create a database

     //Create a table in that database.

     //Dump the values of attributes obtained from my code to that table.



    }
   }
}
```

Question: 
I need to connect to my SQL server 2008 server
Create a database
Create a table in that database.
Dump the values of attributes obtained from my code to that table.

Your help/suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C), a guide to connect to SQL Server through C#.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that. I found much easier way to open sql server from my code. i.e., using SMO. Thanks.